Styled Unicode Characters to Plain Text
I have this code that converts plain text to Unicode styled characters:
function convertText(text, style) {

  // 1. Convert the text to the bold type with the unicode.
  const conv = {
    c: function(text, obj) {return text.replace(new RegExp(`[${obj.reduce((s, {r}) => s += r, "")}]`, "g"), e => {
      const t = e.codePointAt(0);
      if ((t >= 48 && t <= 57) || (t >= 65 && t <= 90) || (t >= 97 && t <= 122)) {
        return obj.reduce((s, {r, d}) => {
          if (new RegExp(`[${r}]`).test(e)) s = String.fromCodePoint(e.codePointAt(0) + d);
          return s;
        }, "")
      }
      return e;
    })},
    bold: function(text) {return this.c(text, [{r: "0-9", d: 120734}, {r: "A-Z", d: 120211}, {r: "a-z", d: 120205}])},
    italic: function(text) {return this.c(text, [{r: "A-Z", d: 120263}, {r: "a-z", d: 120257}])},
    boldItalic: function(text) {return this.c(text, [{r: "A-Z", d: 120315}, {r: "a-z", d: 120309}])},
  };

  if(style == 'bold')
    return(conv.bold(text));
  else if(style == 'italic')
    return(conv.italic(text));
  else if(style == 'bolditalic')
    return(conv.boldItalic(text));
  else
    return text;
}

which I have found on this StackOverflow link:
Google script string with style
I tried reversing the code to convert the styled unicode characters to plain text but failed. Hopefully somebody could reverse the code to get the plain text from the styled unicode characters.

Please show what you tried.  I assume you extended conv with some new functions like unbold.

First, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. About your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize again.

Building on Tanaike's work, here's a function that will accept any text and return it formatted or plain, as requested.
/**
* Converts text to bold, italic or plain Unicode characters, as in
* ' ', ' ', ' ', 'Sample text'.
* Numbers can be bolded but not italicized.
*
* @param {"A2:D42"} text Text strings to format.
* @param {"bold italic"} style One of "bold", "italic", "bold italic" or "plain".
* @return {String[][]} The formatted text.
* @customfunction
*/
function unicodeFormat(text, style) {
  // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/79113754/13045193
  const conv = {
    c: (text, spec) =>
      text.replace(new RegExp(`[${spec.reduce((s, { r }) => s += r, '')}]`, 'g'), e => {
        const t = e.codePointAt(0);
        if (!((48 <= t && t <= 57) || (65 <= t && t <= 90) || (97 <= t && t <= 122))) return e;
        return spec.reduce((s, { r, d }) => e.match(new RegExp(`[${r}]`)) ? String.fromCodePoint(e.codePointAt(0) + d) : s, '');
      }),
    plain: function (text) { return text.normalize('NFKC') },
    bold: function (text) { return this.c(text, [{ r: '0-9', d: 120734 }, { r: 'A-Z', d: 120211 }, { r: 'a-z', d: 120205 }]) },
    italic: function (text) { return this.c(text, [{ r: 'A-Z', d: 120263 }, { r: 'a-z', d: 120257 }]) },
    bolditalic: function (text) { return this.c(text, [{ r: '0-9', d: 120734 }, { r: 'A-Z', d: 120315 }, { r: 'a-z', d: 120309 }]) },
  };
  const s = String(style).toLowerCase().split(' ').sort().join('').replace(/[^a-z]/g, '');
  if (!conv[s]) throw new Error(`uniCodeFormat expected a style of "bold", "italic", "bold italic" or "plain", but got "${style}" instead.`);
  const _format = (text) =>
    Array.isArray(text)
      ? text.map(_format)
      : text || text === 0 ? conv[s](conv.plain(String(text))) : null;
  return _format(text);
}

Supports arrays of text. Can re-format already formatted text. The function can be called from another JavaScript function, or directly from a spreadsheet formula as a custom function.
Here's a short test function that converts text to various formats, then converts those formatted strings back to plain text:
function test() {
  const formattedArray = ['bold', 'italic', 'bold italic', 'plain']
    .map(format => unicodeFormat('Sample text 1234567890', format));
  const plainArray = unicodeFormat(formattedArray, 'plain');
  console.log(formattedArray);
  console.log(plainArray);
}

To test this as a custom function, enter text in column A and put this formula in row 1 of a free column:
=unicodeFormat(A1:A, "bold italic")


Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about the following sample script?
Sample script:
In this sample, normalize() is used.
function convertText(text, style) {

  // 1. Convert the text to the bold type with the unicode.
  const conv = {
    c: function (text, obj) {
      return text.replace(new RegExp(`[${obj.reduce((s, { r }) => s += r, "")}]`, "g"), e => {
        const t = e.codePointAt(0);
        if ((t >= 48 && t <= 57) || (t >= 65 && t <= 90) || (t >= 97 && t <= 122)) {
          return obj.reduce((s, { r, d }) => {
            if (new RegExp(`[${r}]`).test(e)) s = String.fromCodePoint(e.codePointAt(0) + d);
            return s;
          }, "")
        }
        return e;
      })
    },
    bold: function (text) { return this.c(text, [{ r: "0-9", d: 120734 }, { r: "A-Z", d: 120211 }, { r: "a-z", d: 120205 }]) },
    italic: function (text) { return this.c(text, [{ r: "A-Z", d: 120263 }, { r: "a-z", d: 120257 }]) },
    boldItalic: function (text) { return this.c(text, [{ r: "A-Z", d: 120315 }, { r: "a-z", d: 120309 }]) },
  };

  if (style == 'bold')
    return (conv.bold(text));
  else if (style == 'italic')
    return (conv.italic(text));
  else if (style == 'bolditalic')
    return (conv.boldItalic(text));
  else
    return text;
}

// Please run this function.
function sample() {
  const srcText = "Sample Text";

  const t1 = convertText(srcText, "italic");
  const t2 = convertText(srcText, "bold");
  const t3 = convertText(srcText, "bolditalic");

  const text1 = Array(3).fill(srcText).join("");
  const text2 = t1 + t2 + t3;
  const text3 = text2.normalize("NFKC");

  console.log({ text1, text2, text3 });
}

When this script is run, the following result is obtained. In this case, I thought that NFKC and NFKD might be able to be used.
{
  "text1":"Sample TextSample TextSample Text",
  "text2":"   ",
  "text3":"Sample TextSample TextSample Text"
}

In this sample output, the original text is converted to italic, bold, and bolditalic and the converted text is also converted to normal text. text1, text2, and text1 are the source text, and the converted text, and the normal text converted from the converted text, respectively.
Testing:


function convertText(text, style) {

  // 1. Convert the text to the bold type with the unicode.
  const conv = {
    c: function (text, obj) {
      return text.replace(new RegExp(`[${obj.reduce((s, { r }) => s += r, "")}]`, "g"), e => {
        const t = e.codePointAt(0);
        if ((t >= 48 && t <= 57) || (t >= 65 && t <= 90) || (t >= 97 && t <= 122)) {
          return obj.reduce((s, { r, d }) => {
            if (new RegExp(`[${r}]`).test(e)) s = String.fromCodePoint(e.codePointAt(0) + d);
            return s;
          }, "")
        }
        return e;
      })
    },
    bold: function (text) { return this.c(text, [{ r: "0-9", d: 120734 }, { r: "A-Z", d: 120211 }, { r: "a-z", d: 120205 }]) },
    italic: function (text) { return this.c(text, [{ r: "A-Z", d: 120263 }, { r: "a-z", d: 120257 }]) },
    boldItalic: function (text) { return this.c(text, [{ r: "A-Z", d: 120315 }, { r: "a-z", d: 120309 }]) },
  };

  if (style == 'bold')
    return (conv.bold(text));
  else if (style == 'italic')
    return (conv.italic(text));
  else if (style == 'bolditalic')
    return (conv.boldItalic(text));
  else
    return text;
}

// Please run this function.
function sample() {
  const srcText = "Sample Text";

  const t1 = convertText(srcText, "italic");
  const t2 = convertText(srcText, "bold");
  const t3 = convertText(srcText, "bolditalic");

  const text1 = Array(3).fill(srcText).join("");
  const text2 = t1 + t2 + t3;
  const text3 = text2.normalize("NFKC");

  console.log({ text1, text2, text3 });
}

sample();



Reference:

normalize()


Thanks a lot Tanaike, the normalize function works! I did not know that this function exists. Thanks a ton!

@Roderick Latoza About Thanks a lot Tanaike, the normalize function works! I did not know that this function exists. Thanks a ton!, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer
